# Set parameter to super view after dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, dismiss

I have 2 view (view A and view B).

In viewA when I touch a button I execute this code to flip a viewB:

```
viewB.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:viewB animated:YES];
```

And now when I came back to viewA I use this code:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; //here is my problem
```

I need to set same parameters to viewA when I execute dismiss.
How can I do it?

**EDIT**
I have not found any solution and I used a pushNavigation in this way:

```
FirstViewController *viewA = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myView"];

// Effettuo il push alla view successiva
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewA animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am not quite following what you are saying. What parameters are you trying to set on viewA? Are you trying to present viewA modally from viewB as well?

Comment: probabily I have same mistake, but my obiective is to push to the viewB when I touch inside a button in viewA. Now in this view(viewB) I set same parameter and when I touch inside a button in viewB I came back to viewA passing same parameter. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

search for a delegate example or simply use NSNotificationCenter to send a message from one view to another

ClassA:

```
@protocol myDelegate

@interface ClassA : UIViewController {

}

@end

@protocol myDelegate
- (void)thingsDone:(id)someValues;
@end
```

ClassB:

```
#import "ClassA.h"
@interface ClassB : UIViewController <myDelegate> {

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1- You can use the [delegate pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c) and register viewA as the delegate object:

```
viewB.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:viewB animated:YES];
```

And in viewB you can send messages to the delegate:

```
[delegate someMethod];
```

2- You can keep a pointer to viewA in viewB:

```
viewB.viewA = self;
[self presentModalViewController:viewB animated:YES];
```

And then you can send messages to the viewA directly:

```
[viewA someMethod];
```

Comment: why when I try to use viewB.delegate = self the method delegate don't exist for the viewB?

Comment: Refer to this question to know how you can make and use delegates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c